# Remove Next line at the beginning of a string in php

Tags: php

Im planning to remove all the Next line at the beginning of the string,
i tried using. `str_replace("\n",null,$resultContent)` it gives me the result that all Next line are removed.

Example. i need to remove the next line at the beginning of this string

"

String here

String following."

I need to delete the next line at the beginning

Comment: Just use `ltrim` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php .

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this page .

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

use `ltrim($resultContent,"\n")` to remove all new line chars from starting of string.

Answer (score 0):

Just explode and take the first result 
Do not forget to do some test : **if !is_array()** .....

```
$x = explode("\n", $resultContent);
$resultContent = $x[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it like this:

```
if(startsWith($resultContent, '\n')) {  // true:  if string starts with '\n'
    str_replace("\n",null,$resultContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you just want to strip blank lines, or remove everything after the `\n` from the first instance of a word... went with the former so hopefully this is what you're after:

```
$string = "String first line

string second line";


$replaced = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', PHP_EOL, $string);
echo $replaced;
```

Returns:

```
String first line 
string second line
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) is what you're looking for:

> ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a
> string!

```
echo $result_string = ltrim($string);
```

Comment: @john any updates ? Accept and upvote if helped! thanks!